# Respond with error webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

This seems rather trivial, but just need a bit of best practice guidance.

Building a webapp2 Python project (fairly new to both)

I have a profile page, from which you can upload a new profile picture.

My Profile page is fairly trivial, it has a form with file input that submits to the ProfileImageUpload handler.

```
class Profile(Handler):
def get(self):
    #renders page
```

and an image upload handler

```
class ProfileImageUpload(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('img')  
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

        if self.validate_file(blob_info):
            #save the user blob
            #redirect to profile page
        else:
            #redirect to profile page with error
```

my mappings are

```
('/user([0-9]+)', Profile),
('/profileupload', ProfileImageUpload),
```

So on the happy case my imageUpload handler redirects back to the Profile page i.e.

```
/user<userid>
```

but on the error case, I would like to redirect back and display the error, but I cannot work out a way to do this without having the error in the URL i.e. /user?error='something'

Ideally i don't want this in the URL am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Or no redirect and send a page with the error. In this page you can post to .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the easiest, most straight forward way to do this would be to use [sessions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html)

You could have a session key, say errors, which would be a list.  If the list exists and is non-empty then display the errors.  If the list is empty, then there are no errors.  You would need to make sure you pull the current errors out into a variable for display purposes, then wipe the session variable so the errors are only displayed once.

Comment: Yeh that was what i was thinking as well, wanted a narrower scope if one existed.